# python isort utility 1st party import and 3rd party imports issue

Tags: python, isort

I have a project directory structure as follows:

```
Project_Name
|-project_name
|--__init__.py
|--file1.py
|--file2.py
|--main.py
|-tests
|-docs
|-pyproject.toml
```

My isort config is in the root `Project_Name/pyproject.toml` and the .py files are in the subdir `Project_Name/project_name/xxx.py`

If I import as follows, from let's say `main.py`

```
from file1 import xyz
from file2 import abc
```

isort will classify file1 and file2 as third party imports as opposed to first party which are files of the same application.

If I drop the pyproject.toml into the `Project_Name/project_name/`, among the .py files, then it works and file1 and file2 are now addressed as first party imports.

I tried adding this to the config file `known_first_party = ['project_name']` but even with that file1 and file2 are still considered as third party imports.
Is there a way to leave the pyproject.toml in the root dir and still get file1 and file2 identified as first party?

here is my pyproject.toml

```
[tool.isort]
line_length = 120
use_parentheses = true
multi_line_output = 3
ensure_newline_before_comments = true
include_trailing_comma = true
split_on_trailing_comma = true
float_to_top = true
indented_import_headings = false
known_future_library = ['__future__', 'config']
extra_standard_library = []
known_third_party = []
known_mylib = ['my_utils_library']
known_first_party = []
known_local_folder = []
```

Comment: can you show your `pyproject.toml`? https://pycqa.github.io/isort/docs/configuration/config_files.html#pyprojecttoml-preferred-format I suspect you need a `[tool.isort]` section with `src_paths = ["project_name"]`

Comment: @Anentropic just added the pyproject.toml

Comment: try adding the `src_paths`... without that it thinks you should be doing `from project_name.file1 import xyz`

Comment: @Anentropic adding `src_paths` is the correct solution! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add a directive to the `[tool.isort]` section of your `pyproject.toml`:

```ini
src_paths = ["project_name"]
```

Without that isort thinks you should be doing `from project_name.file1 import xyz` and when it sees `from file1` it thinks that must be a 3rd party lib.

See https://pycqa.github.io/isort/docs/configuration/config_files.html#pyprojecttoml-preferred-format